# How to search Ctr+v and Ctrl+b in text?

Tags: python, regex, vim

I received a tsv file which use ^B as delimiter of columns. I was told to use 'ctrl-v + ctrl-b' to match the delimiter. How to do this exactly in Python code or VIM? I want to split each line into columns by this delimiter. I am on Mac. I tried to press ctr+b and ctr+c but with no luck.

```
012^B10420
```

Comment: You were "told to use 'ctrl-v + ctrl-b'" but you "press ctr+b and ctr+c"? No wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, use `\x02`.

In Vim, to type the character ^B, for instance in a search and replace, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: You would use the `\%x02` atom in Vim.